# add options to select - multiple selects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 selects and I want to append the options to all 4 selects using their class.

```
// groupings is just an array of strings 

createElement: function(el, value, html) {
  var htmlText = html || value;
  var elm = document.createElement(el);
  elm.value = value;
  elm.innerHTML = htmlText;
  return elm;
}
var htmlOptions = [];

$.each(groupings, function(i, e) {
  htmlOptions.push(_util.createElement("option", e));
});


$('.groupBy_impact').append(htmlOptions);
```

This seems to work in Chrome, but in IE and Firefox, the values are overflown outside the select box. Not sure why.

If I do the following then it works cross-browser, but I want to avoid it

```
$('#select_groupBy_impact_1').append(htmlOptions);
$('#select_groupBy_impact_2').append($(htmlOptions).clone());
$('#select_groupBy_impact_3').append($(htmlOptions).clone());
$('#select_groupBy_impact_4').append($(htmlOptions).clone());
```

Comment: sure you don't have elements other than selects with `groupBy_impact` css class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, if you want to avoid cloning.

```
$('.groupBy_impact').each(function() {
    $(thid).append(htmlOptions);
});
```

This avoids cloning and iterates through all the elements in the collection.
It is important that all the elements you need to use this on, have the `groupBy_impact` class.

Furthermore [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) can take in different parameters.

You are using jQuery, why not make your `.createElement();` return jQuery objects that are put into an array. this will be easier for jQuery to handle.

Or even better. Create a new jQuery collection (instead of an array) and append the created jQuery objects to that empty jQuery object, essentially creating a new collection of DOM elements to add.

Comment: I guess you can not avoir cloning. In your answer `$(this).append(htmlOptions.clone());` should work

Comment: this worked actually. what would be a jquery object in this case?

Comment: `.append()` usually removes the original element, however we are working with an array of elements, which is a different case so we should be able to simply add the elements over and over

Comment: a jQuery object is created every time you use the $, for instance the selector creates a jQuery collection, all jQuery functions return the jQuery object (for chaining, e.g. `$('selector').fadeIn().fadeOut()`)

Comment: Hmmn, odd... Best option there I guess would be cloning the list. the big plus is that the function still iterates, which saves you a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        var htmlOptions_len = htmlOptions.length;
        for(var i= 0;i<htmlOptions_len;i++ ){
            $('.groupBy_impact').append(htmlOptions[i]);
        }
```

or simply try something like this

```
        $.each(groupings, function(i, e) {
            $('.groupBy_impact').append(_util.createElement("option", e));
        });
```